# Change of vector basis

Tags: linear-algebra

For the bit underlined in orange I understand how to show this result by maths, but i'm struggling to accept it conceptually. $P$ is a change of basis matrix from $E$ to $F$ , so why does P map $[v]_F$ back to $[v]_E$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ and $F = \{f_1,...,f_n\}$.
Let me use $v_E,v_F$ to denote the coordinates of $v$ in the bases $E,F$ respectively.

The change of basis matrix from $E$ to $F$ is defined by $f_i = \sum_j [P]_{ji} e_j$ (note order of indices on $P$). In other words,
$[f_i]_E = \begin{bmatrix} [P]_{1i} \\ \vdots \\ [P]_{ni}  \end{bmatrix}$, that is, the $i$th column of $P$ are the coordinates of $f_i$ in the basis $E$, or
$[f_i]_E = P \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$, where the $1$ is in the $i$th position.

The key here is that the coordinates are unique, so if $v = \sum_k \alpha_k e_k = \sum_k \beta_k f_k$ then $\alpha_k = [v_E]_k, \beta_k = [v_F]_k$.

Choose $v$. Then $v = \sum_i [v_E ]_i e_i = \sum_i [v_F ]_j f_j = \sum_i [v_F ]_j \sum_j [P]_{ji} e_j = \sum_j \left( \sum_i [P]_{ji} [v_F]_i\right) e_j$.

By uniqueness, we have $[v_E ]_i = \sum_j [P]_{ij} [v_F]_j $ (I have swapped $i,j$ above), which is $v_E = P v_F$.